# Подскажите как подключить данную библиотеку

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-navigation-drawer, lib

Есть библиотека https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-drawer
Вопрос
не в том даже как её подключить, а какой активити выбрать для проекта, Empty или Navigation Drawer Activity.
Просто только начинаю осваивать Android разработку, мне как новичку непонятны его инструкции, мне что-то дополнительно нужно создавать, помимо того что он привёл свои style и drawer

Comment: Всегда берите `Empty Activity` - вам точно не захочется пытаться что-то менять в шаблонах - это слишком сложно. Тем паче, что вы хотите взять стороннюю реализацию `Navigation Drawer`

Comment: Эту библиотеку уже можно считать устаревшей. Как новичку я бы советовал разобраться с drawer из стандартрой библиотеки поддержки: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer